# Born into the right house

Tags: expressions

What does it mean to be "born into the right house". Sample: "He is born into the right house".

Comment: I don't understand why the question got down-voted. Could the down-voter explain why?

Comment: Because it is lacking in context. _The right house_ is not an idiom, it just means precisely what it says. That means that its exact meaning depends entirely on the context it's used in. For all we know, _house_ here could be an astronomical thing relating to stars and planets and their houses; or it could mean a family line; or it could simply be a brick-and-mortar house. There is no way to tell without context, and as such, your question cannot be conclusively answered the way it is now.

Comment: Adding "He is" does not provide much context, could you please provide some more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that the house where a person is born (which may be indicative of the family into which they're born) brings advantage - typically wealth, power, and/or social status, but perhaps an environment or lifestyle that's advantageous in enabling or encouraging some manner of success in whatever field....

Answer (score 1):

I can see an alternative meaning. "He got it honest" is a colloquialism in the southern United States. The meaning is that a persons physical or behavioral traits align with their stated lineage/parentage. I could see "born into the right house" as a much more eloquent phrasing of the same concept.